# postgresql: Select a series of date with conditions and remove the in between dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get a series of data that will give me consecutive dates that are at least 14 days apart.

For example:

| userid | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 |
| 1 | 1/5/2022 |
| 1 | 1/31/2022 |
| 1 | 2/22/2022 |

Expected Output:

| userid | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 |
| 1 | 1/31/2022 |
| 1 | 2/22/2022 |

I am stuck at how do i remove 1/5/2022 from the data? I not even sure which function i can try to use in postgresql.

TIA

Comment: 31-Jan is 14+ days from 5-Jan.  What logic has you keep 1-Jan but discard 5-Jan when either would appear to satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LAG` window functions to check for consecutive dates. After that, you can check whether your date is bigger than your previous date + 14 days.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(date_) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_) AS prevdate
    FROM tab
)
SELECT userid, date_
FROM cte
WHERE date_ > prevdate + INTERVAL '14 day' OR prevdate IS NULL
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8CstKSQCzrN1JcgjRZMH7i/1).